# i want python script to copy the files form one folder to another folder based on created date and time?

Tags: python, xml

I want a Python script to copy the files from one folder to another folder based on the creation date and time.

Suppose the creation date of the file is 22-2-2023 and the time is 6 am so my script copies the files which are having date 22-2-2023 and the time should be 6 or above 6 am.

```
import os
import glob
import time
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
from xml.dom import minidom
import logging


for oneFile in minidom.parse('fileconfig.xml').getElementsByTagName('file'):
        sourcePath = oneFile.getElementsByTagName("sourcepath")[0].firstChild.data.replace('\"','')
        mockPath = oneFile.getElementsByTagName("mockpath")[0].firstChild.data.replace('\"','')
    

   

                            ########################################################################    
    
        path = sourcePath
        mock = mockPath
            #we shall store all the file names in this list
        filelist = []
        todelete = []
            #chkDate = "18/02/2023"
        chkDate = '02/21/2023 06:00:00'
        chkTime = "06:00"
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
              for file in files:
            #append the file name to the list
                  filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))

#print all the file names

        for file_path in filelist:
            #if time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y :: %H:%M',time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path))) >= "06/02/2022 :: 06:00":
        #timestamp_str = time.strftime(  '%d/%m/%Y :: %H:%M',time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path))) 
        #date = time.strftime(  '%d/%m/%Y',time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path))) 
        #time = time.strftime(  '%H:%M',time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path))) 
        #if timestamp_str>= "06/02/2022 :: 06:00":
            date = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path))) 
        
            date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(chkDate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        
            if date_time_obj >= datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'):#and time>= time.strftime("06:00"):
            #datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
            #print(timestamp_str, ' -->', file_path)
            #print(datetime.strftime(chkDate,'%d/%m/%Y'), ' -->', file_path)
              print(date, ' -->', file_path)
              todelete.append(os.path.join(root,file))

              source = file_path
 
                # Destination path
              destination = mock
 
            # Copy the content of   
            # source to destination
              dest = shutil.copy2(source, destination)
            #dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
 
            # List files and directories
            # in "/home / User / Documents"
              print("After copying file:")    
            
 
            # Print path of newly
            # created file
              print("Destination path:", dest)
        else:
            {
                print("error check the date and time of file ")
            }
```

Comment: If this code is not doing what you want, then explain what it is doing currently, and explain how that is different from what you wanted.

Comment: Please set up a [mcve] by posting sample of XML as creation dates appear to be derived from XML and not file level metadata. Also, can your run your code through an online Python formatter to fix excessive spacing and line breaks?

Comment: Why did you tag this "xml"? XML is not mentioned in the question.